# Can I use awk in a conditional statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I need to be able to search a user file and determine whether an input from a user is in that file.
This does not work

```
if [ $uname == awk '{print $1}' user_file ]; then echo "success";  fi
```

basically I am looking for a way to return true if the name is in my user_file. Any examples I find of using if/then deal with integers for comparison. Can you not compare strings in bash?

user_file contains

```
username1 password
username2 password2
```

I am trying to write a script that checks that user_info file and if the user has entered the correct username and password then it will perform some other action.

```
if [ username/password in user_info ]; then [ do some other action ]
```

(yes, this is an assignment for a class. The instructor isn't great so I'm stuck googling and trying to figure out a lot of things on my own. So I'm not trying to get exact answers to my scripting question, I just need to figure out how if/then loops work with strings.)

Comment: Add output of `file user_file` to your question, too. `file` is a command and no placeholder.

Comment: To explain why the original doesn't work: things inside a `[ ]` test expression aren't treated as commands, so when you put `awk '{print $1}' user_file` there, it's just three plain strings (which don't make any sense as part of a test expression). You'd have to put `$( )` around it to tell the shell to execute it and use the output, and double-quotes around *that* to tell it not to split the results weirdly, and even that wouldn't work because it'd produce the entire list of usernames, and one username isn't going to be equal to the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

```
if awk -v uname="$uname" '$1==uname{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' user_file; then echo "success"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

- `uname` is `"${u1}"` here, and
- `pword` is `"${p1}"`

I intentionally put the only copy of it in the 2nd to last row to make sure it has to scan through the whole file -

unless you're talking about `9 GB` or larger file, I think one can save more time to scan it once it's all loaded instead of row by row and doing it piecemeal - `1.35GB` input confirmed either found or not within `1.2 secs` :::

```
    % f='test_userpass2.txt' ;
      ( time ( pvE0 <  "${f}" \
         \
         | mawk2 '
           END { exit +RS^index($+RS,__)   # this version won't match
                                           # because i hyphenated them
                  
           }' RS='^$' __="${u1}-${p1}" FS='^$' \
      )
      echo "\n\n exit code : ${?}\n" ) | ecp            
      sleep 3; 
      ( time ( pvE0 < "${f}" \ 
        \
         | mawk2 '
           END { exit +RS^index($+RS,__) 
                  
            }' RS='^$' __="${u1} ${p1}" FS='^$' ) ;
      
       echo "\n\n exit code : ${?}\n" ) | ecp; 

 
      in0: 1.35GiB 0:00:00 [3.46GiB/s] [3.46GiB/s][========>] 100% 

     ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | mawk2 'END { exit +RS^index($+RS,__) }' RS='^$'  ; )

    0.54s user 0.64s system 101% cpu 1.160 total


 exit code : 1

 
 
      in0: 1.35GiB 0:00:00 [3.43GiB/s] [3.43GiB/s][=========>] 100% 
       
     ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | mawk2 'END { exit +RS^index($+RS,__) }' RS='^$'  ; )  

 0.56s user 0.61s system 98% cpu 1.191 total


 exit code : 0
```